# Which Unicode symbols are allowed as operators in PureScript?

Tags: purescript

I'm trying to define `¡¡` (two inverted exclamation marks) as an operator in PureScript, but the compiler complains about an unexpected '¡' character. My definition looks like so:

```hs
infixl 8 functionName as ¡¡
```

The equivalent definition works fine in Haskell, so PureScript's rules about which Unicode characters are allowed must be different, but I can't find them specified anywhere. I thought it might depend on the Unicode category, but '¡' falls in Other Punctuation, which is a mix of allowed and disallowed characters.

Comment: https://github.com/JordanMartinez/purescript-jordans-reference/issues/532